# removing special character from CSV file

Tags: python, data-wrangling

I read my csv file as pandas dataframe. Originally it's a dict with multiple entries per keys. Its looks like this after reading as pandas dataframe:

```
aad,"[1,4,77,4,0,0,0,0,3]"
bchfg,"[4,1,7,8,0,0,0,1,0]"
cad,"[1,2,7,6,0,0,0,0,3,]"
mcfg,"[0,1,0,0,0,5,0,1,1]"
```

so I want to firstly remove the double quotes" symbol from the file and then want to create a new csv file from previous one with consecutive three entries in each row.

```
aad,1,4,77
aad,4,0,0
aad,0,0,3
bchfg,4,1,7
bchfg,8,0,0
bchfg,0,1,1
cad,1,2,7
cad,6,0,0
cad,0,0,3
mcfg,0,1,0
mcfg,0,0,5
mcfg,0,1,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pandas import read_csv, concat
from ast import literal_eval
df = read_csv('file.csv',header=None,names=['name','value'])
split = df.value.apply(literal_eval).apply(Series).set_index(df.name)
part1 = split.ix[:,:2]
part2 = split.ix[:,3:5]
part3 = split.ix[:,6:]
part2.columns=part3.columns=range(3)
stacked = concat([part1,part2,part3])
```

Note that this yields a different order than what you requested:

```
aad    1  4  77
bchfg  4  1   7
cad    1  2   7
mcfg   0  1   0
aad    4  0   0
bchfg  8  0   0
cad    6  0   0
mcfg   0  0   5
aad    0  0   3
bchfg  0  1   0
cad    0  0   3
mcfg   0  1   1
```

Comment: please check another question, as you have idea of doing it in small batch. you can suggest how to do it on big file .thanks in advane.

Comment: If this question is answered, please "accept" it so other users don't waste time crafting answers.